# How to change a row column in python with user input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was trying to make a tic tac toe game and thought that it is better to make a matrix and then ask user to where to put 0 or X. My code is like this. (since I could not find how to make an empty matrix in python)

```
 board = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]]

print board

mark1 = raw_input("enter 0 or X: ")

r = raw_input("now enter row: ")

c = raw_input("now enter col: ")


board [r] [c] = mark1

print board
```

but board[r][c] is wrong because it says:

```
 board [r] [c] = mark1
```

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Any solution or better way for me to approach this ?

thank you !

Comment: you need to convert the input into integers, with `int(r)`

Comment: or you can use `input()`,  for `r` and `c`, instead of `raw_input()` to get number as `int`...

Comment: thanks.. it worked. @Dadep

Comment: @Ash have in mind that from security perspective `input` shouldn't be used since it's vulnerable to code injection since it evaluates the input (e.g. `__import__("os").system('ls')` will be executed). You should better follow @PRMoureu's advice

Answer (score 0):

The function `raw_input` return strings not int, but list index must be int 
you can do like this:

```
board = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]]    
print board    
mark1 = raw_input("enter 0 or X: ")    
r = raw_input("now enter row: ")    
c = raw_input("now enter col: ")   
board [int(r)] [int(c)] = mark1    
print board
```

My English is not good, I hope you can understand.

Comment: yes, I understood.thanks